# OpsHub Visual Studio Migration Utility - Migration Faliure

Tags: opshub, azure-devops

I am getting the following failure when migrating from TFS to VSO (just src history, not work items).

> com.opshub.eai.tfs.exception.OIMTFSApiExcpetion: OH-TFS-Connector-0030: Error occurred in executing operation getFileInformation. Server Error : Unable to read data from the transport connection: The connection was closed.

Any ideas what could cause this? I tried doing the migration from scratch and I got the same error at a similar but not identical changeset.

Comment: Please share relevant trace from the logs. Logs are located at C:\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility\logs\. And which version of TFS are you migrating from?

Comment: Yes, please share the trace from OpsHubTFSService.log from that location.